# Python - regex with Japanese letters matches only one character

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode

I'm trying to find certain words in Japanese addresses so I can scrub them. If there is a single character, regex works fine, but they don't seem to find strings that are 2 characters or more:

```
import re
add = u"埼玉県川口市金山町１２丁目１－１０４番地"

test = re.search(ur'["番地"|"丁目"]',add)
print test.group(0)

丁
```

I can use `re.findall` instead of `re.search`, but it puts all of its findings into a tuple, so then I have to parse the tuple. If that's the best way to do it I can live with it but I figure I'm missing something.

In the example above, I want to swap "丁目" with a dash and remove the trailing "番地", so that the address reads thusly:

埼玉県川口市金山町１２－１－１０４

Comment: You don't have to "parse" a tuple; you just iterate over it with a `for` statement—or, if you're sure there's exactly one, just do `[0]`.

Comment: @abernert, I meant "paruse", not "parse". Either way, I was not using the right regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `|` inside the character classes (`[....]`). It will match any characters listed there; which is not what you want.

Specify the pattern without character classes. (also without `"`)

```
>>> import re
>>> add = u"埼玉県川口市金山町１２丁目１－１０４番地"
>>> test = re.search(ur'番地|丁目', add)
>>> test.group(0)
u'\u4e01\u76ee'
>>> print test.group(0)
丁目
```

To get what you want, use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) (`unicode.repalce`) and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
>>> print re.sub(u'番地$', u'', add.replace(u'丁目', u'－'))
埼玉県川口市金山町１２－１－１０４
```

`$` is used to match only at the end of the string. If the position of `番地$` does not matter, regular expression is not needed. `str.replace` is enough:

```
>>> print re.sub(u'番地$', u'', add.replace(u'丁目', u'－'))
埼玉県川口市金山町１２－１－１０４
```

Comment: thank you, that was what I was looking for. In this case, the end of the string matters because if "番地" appears at the end of the address I want to remove it, I don't want to replace it with a "-".